# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext)

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have developed a Java Camel project that moves files from `resources/data/inbox` to a SFTP server.

When I run it I get this message:

> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java... log4j:WARN No appenders could be
>   found for logger (org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   Process finished with exit code 0

I dont really understand what that warning message means. Can anyone explain how I can deal with it?

Comment: Do you have a log4j.xml file in your classpath?